# Troubleshoot Application Insights telemetry - a local log or have it surface exceptions?

Tags: .net-core, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I have a .NET Core application that does a number of interesting things: upon receiving a message on a Rabbit MQ bus it calls some external APIs (REST over HTTP) to obtain some data, asynchronously uploads several bigger files to Azure Storage and upon completion of one certain file upload (not necessarily last to finish uploading) it sends a completion message to a Rabbit MQ exchange and then waits for all uploads to complete and then resumes listening to incoming messages. Actually, you can freely ignore all the above, that was just to explain that events might occur in different order.

The whole application is instrumented with logging via Serilog which also has a trace sink towards the Application Insights. Additionally, the App. Insights TelemetryClient is used to wrap larger operations with App.Insights-specific telemetry and establish correlation with external calls to other services. I use the "classic" SDK (telemetryClient.StartOperation("my request event")).

What I observe is that under some very concrete combination of conditions (on a particular instance of Rabbit MQ bus, with a specific number of message headers - of all things!) the telemetry seizes to be sent to Application Insights, as if the client loses connectivity or something else bad happens. So far I flat out don't understand what is going on.

I tried to inspect the instance of TelemetryClient when I know it has "gone over to the bad side" and "visually" see no obvious corruption on it. Quite naturally, the telemetry instrumentation doesn't report any trouble in form of exceptions, either - I guess it is coded to create as little fuss as possible by itself. So, finally, **the question is:** how do I troubleshoot this? Can client-side instrumentation be instructed to either write a local log or to become more verbose in some other way (raise exceptions?). I am able to reproduce this situation in my local debugger while running the service in a local Docker container - anything I can do from the debugger?

Comment: The question remains, but I'd share a little update: in my case the telemetry delivery wasn't being interrupted as I'd suspected. What in fact happened was an unfortunate case of event sampling. Some events got "glued" to their predecessors, based on some common properties I suppose - not something I understand very well. It gives very strange effect in end-to-end transactions, when child events are there, but not the parent (due to having been combined with a previous one). So far I just disabled adaptive sampling and it fixed my issues.

Comment: It's great to hear that you were able to resolve your issue. Could you please document your solution in an answer? It would provide clarity for those encountering similar technical challenges within the community.

Comment: My question was originally about troubleshooting techniques (e.g. logging of the instrumentation's infrastructure). That question remains wide open and I never had it answered. Even though my issue is solved, I'm still clueless as to how to troubleshoot if I have a new reason to do so.